# How to do compare ignoring case in search filter?

Tags: odoo

How to do compare ignoring case in search filter? For instance in the below code

```
ids = self.pool.get('product.product').search(cr, uid, [('name', '=', 'Service'))], context=context)
```

i am comparing the name of the product with string 'Service'. i want to compare ignoring its case something similar to below

```
ids = self.pool.get('product.product').search(cr, uid, [('name'.upper(), '=', 'Service'.upper()))], context=context)
```

I can use 'service'.upper but not 'name'.upper. So how do i compare ignoring its case. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `ilike` operator instead of `=` in search domain. It ignores case.

Try this:

```
ids = self.pool.get('product.product').search(cr, uid, [('name', 'ilike', 'Service'))], context=context)
```

Hope this is what you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks Arya, i forgot that option and new you remembered!! :)